# How can I conditionally display the contents of a table depending on the records' category in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database, iteration

I'm taking my first steps in RoR, trying to display the contents of a table of "incidentals", and sorting them depending on the incidental category. So, for example, I want to show all incidentals belonging to "bath" category (Soap, towels, shamppoo, etc.) in a collapsible in my view, and then show all incidentals belonging to "electro" category (A/C, TV set, remote control, etc.), in another collapsible.

So far, I've managed to actually do that with this code, which I feel is super dirty and inefficient:

```
<ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Baño y Aseo</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
        <table class="striped centered">
          <thead>

          </thead>

          <tbody>
            **<% Incidental.all.each do |incidental| %>
              <% case incidental.category %>
                <% when "bath" %>
                  <tr>
                    <td><%= incidental.item %></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-submit">Pedir</a></td>
                  </tr>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>**
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Electrodomésticos</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        <<table class="striped centered">
          <thead>

          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <% Incidental.all.each do |incidental| %>
              <% case incidental.category %>
                <% when "electro" %>
                  <tr>
                    <td><%= incidental.item %></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-submit">Pedir</a></td>
                  </tr>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

This works, but in order to achieve that I have to run multiple **<% Incidental.all.each do |incidental| %>** loops and iterate through the whole table while displaying only the relevant records with a case block. This looks like a very inefficient and "un-RoR-ish" approach to me.

What I would like to do is going over the "incidental list" *only once* and displaying each item on the appropriate collapsible. How should I go about achieving that?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems like `category` is just a string attribute of Incidental. Instead, consider creating a new Category model and linking each Incidental to a Category with a `belongs_to` association in the latter. This would enable you to iterate over the categories, e.g. `Category.includes(:incidental).all.each do |category| ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a scope setup on your model? I'd try something like:

```
## app/models/incidental.rb
class Incidental < ApplicationRecord
  scope :electro -> { where category: 'electro' }
  ...
  ...

end
```

This will let you do:

```
<% Incidental.electro.each do |incidental| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= incidental.item %></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-submit">Pedir</a></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Which should give your desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

You could try a scope in your Incidental model.

```
scope :filter_by_category, -> (category) { where category: category) }
```

Then use the scope in your controller or view:

```
Incidental.filter_by_category("bath")

Incidental.filter_by_category("electro")
```